# Unhandled exception: Concurrent modification during iteration: Instance(length:1) of '_GrowableList'

Tags: list, dart

I have global variable `jobModelList` declared as:

```
late List<JobModel> jobModelList = <JobModel>[];
```

I have http handler that get data and fill `jobModelList` with data.

```
main() async {

  scanParserProcesses();

   app.get('/get-jobs-status', (req, res) async {
     print("get-jobs-status");
    var result = jobModelList.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList();
     res.json({'data': result});
   });

   app.post('/update-jobs-status', (req, res) async { 
       print("update-jobs-status");
       JobModel job = JobModel.fromJson(req.body);
       jobModelList.removeWhere((element) => element.jobPid == job.jobPid);
       jobModelList.removeWhere((element) => element.jobNumbers.toString() == job.jobNumbers.toString());
       jobModelList.add(job);
       res.json({'data': 'Parser status updated'});
   });
```

I need to scan model periodicly and remove hanging process.

```
scanParserProcesses() {
  Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds:5), (Timer t) async {    
    for(var job in jobModelList) {
        if(job.lastPingDate!.isBefore(DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(minutes: 5))) ) {
          job.parserStatus = ParserStatus.idle; 
          if(job.isMiddlewareAlive ?? false ) {
                if(job.lastPingDate!.isBefore(DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(minutes: 30))) ) { 
                    print("Next PID: ${job.jobPid} is hangs and will be restarted");
                    job.parserStatus = ParserStatus.hanging; 
                }
          } 
        }
      }

  });
    removeDeadInstances();
  }

removeDeadInstances() {
      jobModelList.removeWhere((element) => element.parserStatus ==  ParserStatus.hanging );  
  }
```

But periodically I am getting error:

```
Unhandled exception: Concurrent modification during iteration: Instance(length:1) of '_GrowableList'.
```

And I can't understand how to fix it.

Comment: 1. Are you certain that the error come from modifying `jobModelList`? 2. Are there any other places where you add or remove elements from `jobModelList`? I suspect that  something is asynchronously iterating over `jobModelList`, and your periodic `Timer` callback fires in the middle and mutates the list.  If so, fixes would be: A. Add a locking mechanism to make the `Timer` callback do nothing if `jobModelList` is currently in use. B. Iterate over local *copies* of `jobModelList` instead.

Comment: 1,2. Yes I am pretty sure.  I think that "I suspect that something is asynchronously iterating over" it's a: `scanParserProcesses()`

Comment: I mean something else. `scanParserProcesses`'s `for` loop isn't itself asynchronous; that is, it doesn't yield (i.e., `await`) in the loop body.